# JDeveloper 11.1.2.3 hangs when opening project from JDeveloper 11.1.1.6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdeveloper

I have a problem here which I can't solve. The whole story in short. I have a JavaEE client-server project in JDeveloper 11.1.1.6, where it works like a charm. Recently I  had to upgrade JDeveloper version to the latest 11.1.2.3. The first problem that the standard procedure of migrating project from the older version of JDeveloper to the newer one did not help: IDE was hanging forever all the time with no apparent (for me) reason, log file was silent about that. Then I tried another way: I just created the same project from the beginning and put there all necessary source files, libraries, set project properties etc. Still nothing, but now found the way to obtain a kind of error at least. I ran `C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\jdev.exe` from the command line and got the following:

```
Jan 16, 2013 8:52:09 PM oracle.ideimpl.runner.StarterFactoryDescriptionImpl logError
SEVERE: Incorrect hash-structure value in starter-factory definition
Jan 16, 2013 8:52:10 PM oracle.ideimpl.runner.StarterFactoryDescriptionImpl logError
SEVERE: Incorrect hash-structure value in starter-factory definition
```

But I don't know what could be the next step...
Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be open another jdev11.1.1.6.0 project to make sure that the installation of the latest version is ok. 
I have opened many 11.1.1.6.0 projects in 11.1.2.3.0 without a problem. 
Have you tired to do this on an other pc?

Comment: Yes, I have opened 11.1.1.6 project on different machines with different operating systems (XP and Win7). The result is the same(