# Jdeveloper 12c and Glassfish libs

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jdeveloper

Some time ago I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365031/jdeveloper-11-1-2-3-hangs-when-opening-project-from-jdeveloper-11-1-1-6), but that time I didn't know what was the source of problem. I have an issue with adding Glassfish's (I have tried 3.1.2 and 4) libs to the classpath of my javaee 6 project under Jdeveloper 12c. I want to add $GF_HOME/lib/gf-client.jar and $GF_HOME/modules/security.jar to the classpath (I create a project library for that). After that when I try to debug or launch the project it hangs. The latest Jdeveloper where I can add these jars is 11.1.1.6. I need these files very much, because for example without gf-client.jar I can't instantiate `InitialContext` and hence can't do any lookups on server. I really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your code in JDeveloper it uses WebLogic - are you sure your classes don't interfere with the default WebLogic classes for InitialContext for example?

Another option is to try running your project from JDeveloper on a Glassfish server and see if it works there.
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/glassfish_extension_for_oracle_jdeveloper

Comment: Hello, @Shay! Thank you for reply. I'm not using any Weblogic classes in my application (at least at pointed stage). As for Glassfish extension I have already tried it - still no luck... It doesn't even write any errors to log, just hangs.